# GreenDao generator task in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, greendao

I would like to use GreenDao but I don't want to have seperate project just for dao generator.

Is there possible to make a task in Gradle, which will just generate me a new dao classes and override previous if present?

**UPDATE 1:**

I would like structure like this:

```
src/main/java/model         // output of generator
src/main/java/daoGenerator  // generator source
```

And the only task which which use /src/main/java/daoGenerator and greendao-generator library
would be:

```
gradle generate
```

**UPDATE 2:**

The most awesome would be that, when any task is called, gradle check if anything in `src/main/java/daoGenerator` has changed, if yes then fire `gradle generate` before called task.

Comment: did not get your question be more specific. As i understand you want different source classes with different builds. If is it then ya its possible using product Flavors .Once you clear your I will answer how can you achieve that.

Comment: check my answer once, is it wat you want ?.

Answer (score 0):

First create a directory structure like this

```
src/your_build_type/java/model         // output of generator
src/your_build_type/java/daoGenerator  // generator source
```

Now you can define your own `buildType` in your module's `build.gradle` something like this

```
       buildTypes {
          your_build_type {
            runProguard false
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            debuggable false

        }
```

Defining this will generate a task for you named assembleYour_buildtype , running that task will take sourceSets of your `your_build_type` directory along with `main`. If the same classes present in both than it will take the one lying in `your_build_type` while compilation.

Change and task handling will automatically done by Gradle, watch this awesome introduction by **Hans Dockter** here

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=5a91dBLX8Qc#t=2372

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like the java/withIntegrationTests? I've no experience with GreenDao, and not tested this, but kind a like:

```
sourceSets {
    greendao {
        java.srcDir file('src/greendao/java')
    }
}

task generate(type:JavaCompile){
    mainClassesDir = sourceSets.greendao.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.greendao.runtimeClasspath
}
```

And then just go overboard on the dependsOn, mustRunAfter and so fort. Generate should run if sources are changed, or the output have changed. Maybe the output thing is kind of annoying. So maybe you'd want to override that somehow.